# How to assign speed parameter to callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to figure out how to assign speed to a callback function, but couldn't.

In this program.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="trigger">Try</button>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
height: 1000%;
}
#box
{
position: absolute;
height: 300px;
width: 400px;
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border-color: black;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0;
}
#bottom
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").click(function () {
        var ele = document.getElementById('bottom');
        var pos = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = pos.left;
        var y = pos.top;
        $("#box").animate({
            left: "100px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, "slow", function () {
            window.scrollTo(x, y);
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

On removing the speed from callback, it works but with it no success.
How to assign speed to it, thanks in advance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9C8kr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the speed two times, the last one is not valid.
If you want to animate the scrolling, then do so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").click(function () {
        var ele = document.getElementById('bottom');
        var pos = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x   = pos.left;
        var y   = pos.top;
        $("#box").animate({
            left: "100px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, "slow", function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft : x,
                scrollTop  : y
            }, 'slow');
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9C8kr/2/)

Comment: That's the question, how to assign speed to the callback parameter.

Comment: There is no speed for the callback, it's called when the animation completes ?

Comment: So how can I set speed for window.scrollTo()?

Comment: window.scrollTo() has no speed, do you want to animate that as well ?

Comment: Yes, It's in the answer !